# How to pass XML in curl

Tags: xml

I want to post XML data by using curl. I am using these code lines:

```
            $data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\r\n";
    $data.= "<contacts>\r\n";
    $data.= "<contact>\r\n";
    $data.= "<firstName>$firstName</firstName>\r\n";
    $data.= "<lastName>$lastName</lastName>\r\n";
    $data.= "<email>$Email_Address</email>\r\n";
    $data.= "<status>normal</status>\r\n";
    $data.= "<contact>\r\n";
    $data.= "</contacts>\r\n";

    $url =  "https://app.sandbox.icontact.com/icp/a/".$account_id."/c/".$client_folder_id."/contacts";
        $handle = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
        $response = curl_exec($handle);
```

When I get response,It shows me this message :

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
           <response>
       <errors>
    <error>The XML that was passed in your request was malformed. Please provide valid XML.</error>
       </errors>
           </response>
```

What I need to change in XML input.

Thanks

Comment: This xml code working fine in RestClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its usually a problem where you need to url encode the xml before you send it.  try `$data = urlencode($data)`

This will give you output such as `%3C?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?%3E` etc.

Comment: But it makes different to xml and still getting same problem

Comment: try removing the \r\n as well.  Try it with urlencoding and without.

Comment: I have found solution .I used http://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php?id=1&L=0 and fount error was in closing contact tag